# Unwanted change of the element in the array

Tags: python, arrays

Can somebody explain why `x` changes in the following code?

```
x = np.arange(0, 5, 1)
z = x
for i in range(len(x)):
    z[i] = -z[i]
print(z)
print(x)
```

out:

```
[ 0 -1 -2 -3 -4]
[ 0 -1 -2 -3 -4]
```

How can I prevent `x` from changing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could have just written `z = -x`, that's the whole point of NumPy arrays.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the link you sent is related to lists. But what if I do not want to do casting from array to list and back?

You are right about 'z = -x' ! But in general, I want to change not all elements in 'z', but few of them. So how could I solve this?

Comment: The explanation is valid for both lists and NumPy arrays. You need to make a copy of the array.

Comment: @mkrieger1 you are right! That answers my question

Answer (score -1):

Assigning a list to a variable, copies it by reference. So changing in one list will affect the other.

If you want to copy the values only, you can use `list.copy()` method.

```
import numpy as np


x = np.arange(0, 5, 1)
z = x.copy()
for i in range(len(x)):
    z[i] = -z[i]
print(z)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[ 0 -1 -2 -3 -4]
[0 1 2 3 4]
```